# Scheduling a tech phone interview

Tags: interviewing

Microsoft has an office in the city where I live. It happened that they are hiring software engineers for a team/product that I am really passionate about. So I revamped my resume and tailored it to meet the job description/team. did few days studying and also did my research, The Principle manager for that team posted on LinkedIn that they are hiring. I crafted a personal msg and sent it to him explaining my interest in the team and the product and also a little bit about myself and why I am might be a good fit to the culture/team. At the end of the msg I mentioned that I'll send him a follow up email with my resume, and I did.

All worked out well, he replied to my email after three days and asked If I want to schedule a tech phone interview. That was great! except that In the morning of the same day I contacted a recruiter and asked if they have business with MS so that I increase my chances of being noticed, I've also applied to the position directly. Recruiter said yes they do and in fact they are the only recruiting company in town that does work with MS and that he has a formal relationship with the hiring manager. That was great, I said. So he said, I want you to send me an email and say you want us to represent you, so I did trusting that he knows what he's doing. recruiter mentioned not to reply to MS emails anymore and let him handle it. So for the next two days, I didn't get anything meaningful from the recruiter and I started to feel he is just bluffing and I might miss my chance.

During the weekend followed that, I decided to cancel with the recruiter and reply to the principle manager directly. I did, and explained what happened and said 'yes' to the phone interview. That was on Sunday, and now it is Thursday and didn't hear back from MS. Should I follow up with the principle manager on linkedin? or is it too soon giving that Microsoft just wrapped up with their annual conference yesterday. Does anyone know how long it takes to setup a tech phone interview with MS?

Comment: It'd be helpful to get constructive feedback on why the down vote for?

Comment: I did not downvote, but - you have two questions. First, you're asking if you should follow up with the PM on LinkedIn. That's essentially a duplicate, if you search you'll find lots of other questions asking about following up. Your other question: does anyone know how long it takes to set up a tech phone interview with Microsoft? Is very company-specific, and this SE generally doesn't handle questions on company-specific policy.

Comment: Can you trim unnecessary details, make subject line more descriptive, and make it more generic and shorter question. It's a big wall of text as of now

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got any personal experience with Microsoft but I do have experience with this situation and had ended up shooting myself in the foot by attempting both routes.

I don't know where you're from but in The Netherlands for example most companies that use recruiters have a clause in their contract with the recruiter that they can't have any direct contact with an applicant if they've been supplied via the recruiter.
This is to prevent a company hiring someone directly who was supplied via the recruiter as in that case the recruiter wouldn't receive their recruitment fee.
You did "cancel" the recruiter, however the above clause usually applies for a period of about 6 months.

Even though you had already had prior contact with Microsoft they might not want to risk a disagreement with the recruiter over recruitment fees and if you weren't a good match off the bat they might not want to pay the additional recruitment fee to the recruiter or any additional hassle this might cause them.
You've also had to be processed twice which caused them to spend extra time and effort already.

Personally I learned to only have either direct contact with a company or via a recruiter not both.

Answer (score 1):

They key information is here

> or is it too soon giving that Microsoft just wrapped up with their annual conference yesterday?

If the conference is related in some way to the manager you're talking with, then there's a good chance that he's been wrapped up in working on the conference.  From personal experience of working with Microsoft, this happens - they drop out of the loop while the conference is going on and then come back again.

So, you should chase up via email and feel free to mention something about the conference that you thought appeared to go well.  He might not have been, so don't assume that he did (it's just a good possibility).